# How to pass args to method in java, like f(*args) in python?

Tags: java, python, arguments, variadic-functions

In python, I can do:

```
args = [1,2,3,4]
f(*args) # this calls f(1,2,3,4)
```

Is this possible in java?

to clarify - f has an argument list of variable length.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, you should be able to do precisely that using [vararg-methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). If you're worried about ambiguities when it comes to arguments such as `Object...` this piece of code should clarify:

```
public class Test {

    public static void varargMethod(Object... args) {
        System.out.println("Arguments:");
        for (Object s : args) System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        varargMethod("Hello", "World", "!");

        String[] someArgs = { "Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit" };

        // Eclipse warns:
        //   The argument of type String[] should explicitly be cast to Object[]
        //   for the invocation of the varargs method varargMethod(Object...)
        //   from type Test. It could alternatively be cast to Object for a
        //   varargs invocation
        varargMethod(someArgs);

        // Calls the vararg method with multiple arguments
        // (the objects in the array).
        varargMethod((Object[]) someArgs);

        // Calls the vararg method with a single argument (the object array)
        varargMethod((Object) someArgs);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Arguments:
    Hello
    World
    !
Arguments:
    Lorem
    ipsum
    dolor
    sit
Arguments:
    Lorem
    ipsum
    dolor
    sit
Arguments:
    [Ljava.lang.String;@1d9f953d
```

---

You **can not** do it for a non-vararg method. However, a non-vararg method has a fixed number of arguments, so you should be able to do

```
nonVarargMethod(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
```

Further more, there is no way to let the compiler **resolve the situation for overloaded methods** based on the size or type of the array.

Answer (score 4):

A method can be declared with a varargs parameter, and invoked with an array, as suggested by other answers.

If the method you want to invoke doesn't have a varargs parameter, you can do something like this with introspection, though it's a bit clunky:

```
class MyClass {
  public void myMethod(int arg1, String arg2, Object arg3) {
    // ...code goes here...
  }
}

Class<MyClass> clazz = MyClass.class;
Method method = clazz.getMethod("myMethod", Integer.TYPE, String.class, Object.class);

MyClass instance = new MyClass();
Object[] args = { Integer.valueOf(42), "Hello World", new AnyObjectYouLike() };
method.invoke(instance, args);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is two way to use varargs in java

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

Or

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

In my example it's with string, but you can do it with int too.

To call them (this works on both),

```
main("hello", "world");
```

or

```
main(new String[]{"hello", "world"});
```

Comment: This may not actually be what the OP is asking for - it seems like they're asking if they can pass an array of arguments to a non-vararg function.

Comment: Indeed - it's the opposite of varargs. The OP wants to call a non-array-argument method with an array as its argument.

Comment: Ah, I just realized that arrays are not objects in java, so there is no ambiguity if you pass only one argument. Thank you! :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Call `funct("a", "b", "c")` on `public void funct(String s)` ?!?

Comment: @m01 arrays **are** objects in java.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have passed arguemnts to method at the method call, see the below example,

[check the source](http://www.javalearnsimply.weebly.com/java-blog/passing-arguments-to-methods)

Description for the example is below;

There we have an int variable with value 10 it is a method local variable. Then we call our method m(int x) inside print statement. then in the m(int x) there is a parameter int x variable , this x is also a method local variable. You can access it only within this method. Then inside method you print the value of x , which is 10, because at the method call an argument is passed y, which holds value 10. that value 10 gets assigned to method's method local variable x, which is declared inside the method parameter. Now when we call to print x it will print 10.

Then create another method local variable and add some value to x value and assign and returns that variable. You are returning a value, so now you are going to check that method is not void, and has int return type, since 10 in an int.

Since your method is written inside print statement. your returning value also gets printed at this program. So below is the code.

```
class A
{
     static int m(int x)
     {
          System.out.println("x : "+x);
          int a= x+10;
          System.out.println("a : "+a);
          return a;
     }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         int y=10;
         System.out.println(m(y));
    }
}
```

Output :

```
x : 10
a: 20
20
```